# Httphandler registration not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httphandler

I have a handler called `MsiDownloadHandler` which lets the client download an MSI file if it exists, and otherwise creates an MSI file and lets the client download it.

Though I have registered my handler in `web.config` like this:

```
  <handlers>
    <add name="MsiDownloadHandler" verb="*" path="*.msi" type="MsiDownloadHandler, ManagementConsoleV2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" resourceType="File" />
  </handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

The handler break point is not hit and I always get the error:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: are u using url rewriting?

Comment: You say there is a handler called "MsiDownloadHandler" to the best of my knowledge there is no such standard handler. If you wrote one, you should have the module/dll for it and you need to get it properly registered to prevent a 404 error. Refer to articles on writing, registering and configuring http handlers is IIS (IIS7 introduced important changes). Come back to S/O when you have specific problems.

Comment: @Gary Walker : Since I am registering a handler in config file, i think it gives a context enough to let one understand that i have a custom handler. And this is how one registers a custom handler as per KB articles. And my question is what am i doing wrong in the registration. Isn't that a specific problem? If you don't understand the question or can't answer please refrain from commenting and down-voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used:

```
resourceType="File" />
```

But as you said, your handler is meant to work even if there is no file on the server whose location is mapped to the path of the URI. For such a handler, you want `resourceType="Unspecified"`.